# Python Multiprocessing w/ Map: Running Entire Script, Not Just Sub-function

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to use Python's multiprocessing map function. I have placed the map call inside a sub-function, as I need to loop through a larger data-set to divide it up and call map on the smaller chunks.

My problem is that the time.sleep(5) line is being called multiple times and 'Test!' is printing 5 times (which seems to equal once at the start, and then 2*2 for the number of loops * number of processes), even though it is at a higher level than the multiprocessing calls. At the same time, though, the CSV output is what I expect, so runParallel() is running as expected and being called the expected number of times.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import os,csv,copy,time
from AuxFuncs import *

def master():    
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Test!')
    for mult in [1,10]:
        runParallel(mult)

def runParallel(mult):
    randIntInputs = list()
    for i in range(5): randIntInputs.append((np.random.randint(10)*mult,mult))
    if __name__=='__main__':
        p = Pool(processes=2)
        results = p.map(testFunc,randIntInputs)
        p.close()
        p.join()
        valsToSave = [list(result[0]) for result in results]
        write2dListToCSV(valsToSave,'output' + str(mult) + '.csv')

def testFunc(inputs):
    return np.random.randint(1,10,5) * inputs[0],inputs[1]

master()
```

And the output is:

```
Test!
Test!
Test!
Test!
Test!
```

I thought the problem might be that I put the Pool call in a function, but even if I move it out of a function, I have the same issue ("Test!" is printed 3 times by the below code.)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import os,csv,copy,time
from AuxFuncs import *

def testFunc(inputs):
    return np.random.randint(1,10,5) * inputs[0],inputs[1]

print('Test!')
mult,randIntInputs = 5,list()
for i in range(5): randIntInputs.append((np.random.randint(10)*mult,mult))
if __name__=='__main__':
    p = Pool(processes=2)
    results = p.map(testFunc,randIntInputs)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    valsToSave = [list(result[0]) for result in results]
    write2dListToCSV(valsToSave,'output' + str(mult) + '.csv')
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the help. Looks like this works:

from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import os,csv,copy,time
from AuxFuncs import *

```
def master():    
    if __name__=='__main__':
        time.sleep(5)
        print('Test!')
        for mult in [1,10]:
            runParallel(mult)

def runParallel(mult):
    randIntInputs = list()
    for i in range(5): randIntInputs.append((np.random.randint(10)*mult,mult))
    # if __name__=='__main__':
    p = Pool(processes=2)
    results = p.map(testFunc,randIntInputs)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    valsToSave = [list(result[0]) for result in results]
    write2dListToCSV(valsToSave,'output' + str(mult) + '.csv')

def testFunc(inputs):
    return np.random.randint(1,10,5) * inputs[0],inputs[1]

master()
```

Comment: I'm really quite confused by the way you've chosen to structure your code. Why is `testFunc` nested within `runParallel`? Then you also keep opening and closing the `Pool` inside `runParallel` because that function is being called within a `for` loop in `master()`. I think it would be better to refactor this and then see if that behaviour still exists.

Comment: Ok, the edit makes more sense. If you put `print('Test!')` under `if __name__ == '__main__'` then you should find that it prints only once. Does that work? Are you on Windows?

Comment: Sorry... poor formatting. testFunc is not nested within runParallel. Yes I'm on Windows, and yes putting Test! inside 'if __name__...' does resolve the issue in the second code block. 

I am putting the Pool call essentially inside a for loop because the data set I am working on would take too long if I put it all in a single function call. So I am splitting it into chunks, doing my calculations (w/ multiprocessing) on each chunk, and then saving each chunk.

Comment: OK, your comment made me realize I could just move the if __name__ == '__main__' call into my master() function, and it all seems to work. Like so:

Comment: I really think you should keep the code as in your second example and just shield code that you don't want to run in each child process (like the `print`) with `if __name__ == '__main__'` rather than putting that inside a function

Comment: Can I ask why you don't think I should put `if __name__ == '__main__'` inside a function? I am not a CS guy, so if you could provide a brief explanation or point me in the direction of reading as to why, I would really appreciate it. Given that I want to divide my data set and run several Pool computations sequentially, would it be better to place function calls that divide my data set, then run Pool on each chunk, within the ``if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Answer (score 4):

What's probably happening here is that each process is trying to import the function that your calling. When that happens, it runs any function that is called outside of a definition or is not shielded by an `if`, including your call to `master`. Putting the `if __name__ ...` inside a definition disallows you from using it to shield other operations. What I think you're going for looks more like this:

```
def master():
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Test!')
    for mult in range(1, 11):
        runParallel(mult)

def runParallel(mult):
    randIntInputs = list()
    for i in range(5): randIntInputs.append((np.random.randint(10)*mult,mult))
    with Pool(processes=2) as p:
        results = p.map(testFunc,randIntInputs)
    valsToSave = [list(result[0]) for result in results]
    write2dListToCSV(valsToSave,'output' + str(mult) + '.csv')

def testFunc(inputs):
    return np.random.randint(1,10,5) * inputs[0],inputs[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    master()
```

The difference between this and your very last update is that, in your update master is still called for each process, it just doesn't do anything since the `if` statement doesn't evaluate `True`; but in this code, it only calls `master` once, and is blocked each time after that by the `if` statement. The difference isn't huge, but this version of it is much more practical.

Btw, I took the liberty of putting your pool in a context manager, using the `with` statement. This will automatically close the `Pool` once the context exits. I also removed the `.join()` because the `Pool().map()` function already pauses the main thread until it returns. Lastly, I changed the temporary list you were creating in master to a call to `range`. `range` is used to create a sequence of numbers between the two entered, inclusive to the left but not to the right. With a single parameter it uses 0 as a starting point and goes up to the number specified; `range(10) => 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

Comment: Thanks!! Seems like you and roganjosh are in agreement on where the if-main statement should be, so I've moved it as a wrapper around the main call. Also good to know about the .join() being superfluous and like the while framework. I tried it out on my main script and everything works as intended. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem. Btw, if you're planning on sticking around SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). The general guidelines ask that we do not thank in comments, but instead by up-voting and selecting answers. If you like what I've got here, please do so by checking the big green check mark next to my answer.

Comment: Hey Eric, I had several hours arround this problem and you just saved me :D Thanks!